# Configure wiring for reversing a small geardrive 115v motor

Tags: current

[image]

My question is: Would this same configuration work with 115v system.
Motor; both switches and the relay are 115v 10a and are compatible. Would the diodes D2 & D3 have to be changed to accommodate 115v?
Also the schematic indicates a coil bypass under D3; any ideas as to what this should be? Be gentle guys...virgin prototype here..LOL

It's this motor:
https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/36690741?rItem=36690741

Comment: What, exactly, is that circuit supposed to do? Explain in detail, please, or provide a link to the source.

Comment: 115vAC? I'f that's the case you can't reverse its direction without hacking the motor (unless it comes with extra terminals listing "reversible")

Comment: The motor is reversible and has split capacitors and is 115v AC

Comment: actually it's 115Volt AC, 5 rpm, 680:1 Gear ratio, CM Reversible Gearmotor

Comment: The gear motor drives a chain sprocket that tips a tray 45 degrees each way from level; it's intermittent usage and is only 5 rpm with a 680:1 gear ratio. Once the tray tips 45 degrees one way it contacts the SW2 roller switch that closes and reverses the motor turning the tray the opposite direction to 45 degrees until it contacts the opposite SW3 switches  and then begins the cycle all over again. A timer controls the frequency of the turns

Answer (score 1):

The relay coil is designed for 12 volts DC. If you can control the relay with 12 volts DC, and the contacts are rated for 115 volts AC, the contacts could probably be used in a similar way to reverse an AC motor that is designed to be reversed. The contacts would have no connections to the DC circuit and ground or common. The AC motor connections would be a little more complicated. There are several possible variations depending on the motor design. If the motor is switched directly from forward to reversed without stopping, the motor would need to be rated for that. There is also a question as whether the relay is rated for switching a motor. Just having the proper voltage and current rating is generally not sufficient.

Comment: The coil I'm using is a Potter & Brumfield/TYCO K10P-11A15-120. Accordingly it states: Contact Form: DPDT coil Voltage:120VAC: Contact Rating 15A @ 120VAC coil resistance: 3900 Coil Current: 11mA and is equipped with a compatible mating socket with screw type terminal. Hope this helps.

Comment: In that case, the control of the relay is fine. The diodes would not be used. You could put an resistor with series capacitor across the coil. You can buy an RC module designed for that purpose. The motor specifics are needed to determine the relay contact connections. I believe it is possible to buy three-terminal motor that is reversible. You should revise the question to include the information added in your comments my and another answer. Also show the timer connection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer. The diodes is what  my concern was as I didn't understand their usage in this context. The motor does have 3 wires and I've used it before in other installations, it reverses fine. Here's the  link:https://www.mscdirect.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/details/36690741 My apologies to all for my lack of knowledge regarding the site and questions...1st time user here.

Comment: I can not post a diagram now. Do you have an idea how to proceed from here? I can't do any more for a while.

Comment: The parts are enroute and I think I have enough info to give it a shot once they arrive. The motor has 3 leads and the schematics has only 2 but once I get my hands on the relay I can figure it out. Thanks again for your help...trying to figure out how to post the badges for the answers received here..LOL

Answer (score 0):

Check what motor you have. 115/230V mixed AC/DC motors as found in drills and kitchen machine usually are in series configuration. Reversing them requires to flip *only* the rotor coil connection but not the stator coil. If you only have two terminals at the motor, you are out of luck.

EDIT: Now you have posted a link to the motor, I think it's not an AC/DC motor but an asynchronous AC motor.

You have three wires. One is neutral, the other two are hot and hot+90°. The hot wire goes directly to mains hot, the hot+90° one through the capacitor. When you switch the two hot wires, the motor runs in reverse direction. You can do this by connecting both hot wires with the cap and select which is connected to mains hot by a toggle switch/relay contact.

Comment: The motor is  115v AC, 5 rpm,680:1 gear ratio CM Reversible gearmotor 50Lbs/in. full load torque

Comment: If that motor is advertized as reversible and AC, it needs four terminals. Does it have four terminals?

Comment: hehttps://www.mscdirect.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/details/36690741re's the link: I'm more concerned about the wiring configuration other than the motor. I've used this motor before and it reverses just fine. Using it in this configuration is my question not the reversing of the motor. Thanks

Comment: Your configuration is for DC only. A small DC motor usually has two terminals only because there is not stator winding but a permanent magnet instead. For AC, this doesn't work, because the field in the rotor reverses with the outer AC, so the stator field has to reverse, too, to have a steady momentum in the wanted direction. You cannot achieve this with a permanent magnet. P.S.: your link is 404.

Comment: Found it using the part number. This most likely isn't an AC/DC motor, but an asynchronous AC motor.